# Javascript - find max and min values using loop and array, -Infinity/Infinity

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, numbers

Could someone explain to me how does this work. In find highest number method every number is larger than -Infinity. Why does it take the highest number? Same with lowest number finder, how does it selects lowest number, all of the numbers are smaller than Infinity.

```
//find highest number

var Numbers = [1, 2, 101, 45, 55, 1443];
var l = Numbers.length;
var max = -Infinity;
var i;
for (i = 0; l > i; i++) {

    if (Numbers[i] > max) {

        max = Numbers[i];

    }

}

console.info(max);

//find lowest number

var Numbers = [1, 2, 101, 45, 55, 1443];
var l = Numbers.length;
var max = Infinity;
var i;
for (i = 0; l > i; i++) {

    if (Numbers[i] < max) {

        max = Numbers[i];

    }

}

console.info(max);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is here.

```
if (Numbers[i] > max) {

    max = Numbers[i];

}
```

If the current number is greater than the current maximum number then we make that the max number. And we continue until we go trough the entire array.

Starting with -Infinity ensures that any value in the array will be greater or equal to it.

For the minimum it's the same but we always keep the smallest value we find in the list.

Infinity and -Infinity are values javascript provides, they are greater or smaller than any other value of type [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). You can find more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).

You could debug your code and see exactly what's happening step by step. Check [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) on how to do that in Chrome.

Comment: ahhhhh, i understand now, every time 1 loop finishes, max has new value and depending on whether it's bigger/smaller and the arrow direction it will change

Comment: yup, debugging makes that very clear. Or just try printing the i and max values every time the for loops. :)

Comment: The answer is so obvious, and I was stuck looking at it for so long, haha! Thank you for clearing it so much! ;d

Comment: @JakubMazurkiewicz np, that's what this site is for. Check Sarjan's answer on an example of how to log the values. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using console, you can see that for lowest number `if` condition only true for once when `1` is less than `Infinity`. Other times it always return false because all other numbers are less then `1` so here the logic is if number from array is **lower** than max then it store else loop continues to looping.

Same for highest number.

```js
//find highest number
var Numbers = [1, 2, 101, 45, 55, 1443];
var l = Numbers.length;
var max = -Infinity;
var i;
for (i = 0; l > i; i++) {
  if (Numbers[i] > max) {
    console.log(i + ' max number' + Numbers[i]);
    max = Numbers[i];
  }
}
console.info(max);

//find lowest number
var Numbers = [1, 2, 101, 45, 55, 1443];
var l = Numbers.length;
var max = Infinity;
var i;
for (i = 0; l > i; i++) {
  if (Numbers[i] < max) {
    console.log(i + ' lowest number' + Numbers[i]);
    max = Numbers[i];
  }
}
console.info(max);
```

Comment: The numbers are not in ascending order in the array. Also the same array is used for the minimum value, so that does not make any sense. :)